# Wordpress Twentyfourteen arrange category posts by title

Tags: wordpress

In the wordpress trentyfourteen them I am trying to order a categories posts by title.

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Category pages
*
* @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
* @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
*/

get_header(); ?>

<section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

<?php

 if (have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="archive-header">
            <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );  ?></h1>

            <?php
                // Show an optional term description.
                $term_description = term_description();
                if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
                    printf( '<div class="taxonomy-description">%s</div>', $term_description );
                endif;
            ?>
        </header><!-- .archive-header -->

        <?php

                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next page navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

I have tried adding the following (@ line 18)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

but this does nothing for me. I have also tried

```
     $args=array(

    'showposts'=> 1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'    => 'ASC'

);


query_posts($args);
```

put before

```
if (have_posts() ) : ?>
```

and this does limit the post count to 1, but it grabs the latest post from the wrong category

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $args=array(
'cat' => $cat,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order'    => 'ASC'

);

query_posts($args);
```

works for me. Thank you me